# Cannot access google trends using HttpClient

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, google-api-java-client

I'm kind of newbie to this...Basicly I need to run a script to download .csv files from google trends. I wrote the following code according to this [reference](http://www.vogella.com/articles/ApacheHttpClient/article.html) , the code is like:

```
     HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");

     try {

         List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>;
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", "myEmail"));
         nameValuePairs
                 .add(new BasicNameValuePair("Passwd", "myPasswd"));
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("accountType", "GOOGLE"));
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("source",
                 "Google-cURL-Example"));
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("service", "xapi"));

         post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
         HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
         BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

         String line = "";
         while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
             System.out.println(line);
             if (line.startsWith("SID=")) {
                 String key = line.substring(4);
                 // Do something with the key
         } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
```

I got the information about SID, LSID, Auth, but don't know how to use these information. I guess I should add these cookies in my following request, but don't know exactly how. I wrote another piece of code to connect to the certain URL, but I keep getting this message "You must be signed in to export data from Google Trends." The code is here if it helps:

```
 URL url = new URL(myUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "SID"+key);
        conn.addRequestProperty("Email", "myEmail");
        conn.addRequestProperty("Passwd", "myPasswd");
        conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
        conn.connect();
```

I searched around and found few useful information, anyone could help?

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be in Java? In python, it's as simple as this:

```py
from pyGTrends import pyGTrends

connector = pyGTrends('google username','google password')
connector.download_report(('keyword1', 'keyword2'))
print connector.csv()
```

You'll need the [google trends api library](http://www.juiceanalytics.com/writing/programmatic-google-trends-api/).

If it has to be Java, you may want to look at the [HttpClient examples](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html) from Apache. "Form based logon" and "client authentication" may both be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I have just coded this:

https://github.com/elibus/j-google-trends-api

It is an unofficial Java implementation of Google Trends API. You could use it to easily access Google Trends or you might want to have a look at the code to see it works.

Anyway the authentication flow works as follows (all the steps are required):

1. Fetch https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth and parse the GALX id
2. Post username/password + GALX
3. Get http://www.google.com

Then you can access Google Trend with relaxed QoS policies for authenticated users.

Comment: i don't want to redirect on browser for LogIn is there any solution for it?

Comment: What do you mean? BTW there is a binary client available here: https://github.com/elibus/j-google-trends-client/tree/master/releases/org/freaknet/gtrends/client/j-google-trends-client/1.1